# Installing a Remote Control Ceiling Fan with Light & Different Wire Configuration

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I am replacing an older traditional ceiling fan with black, white, blue and green wires with a new remote control ceiling fan with just black, white and green wires.  The wires coming out of the ceiling are black, white, red and green.  It is connected to a double plate wall switch, one controlling the light and the other controlling the fan (on/off only).  I read quite a few posting stating the fan no longer needs the red wire coming out of the ceiling so cap it and use the remote to control the light. So I am using black to black, white to white and green to green, for grounding.
With this setup, the fan turns on using one of the wall switches but the remote does not control the light or fan speed.  It does nothing.  The other wall switch does nothing too.  Is it possible I need to swap the black wire for the red wire coming out of the ceiling to the black wire to the fan, or it might be a remote control issue? Thanks!

Comment: Read the instructions that came with the fan, and see if there is any reference to DIP switches (or other anti-interference settings).  If there is, make sure the remote and receiver are configured properly.  Also, try fresh batteries in the remote.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that you have the batteries installed in the correct direction in the remote. Some use both positive buttons up, some down, and some one of each.

Second, check that the remote and fan do not have a channel switch. These are usually mounted horizontally on the fan and are frequently labeled A/B or 1/2. If there is one, the fan and the remote must be set to the same value. It doesn't matter which one, use the one that works best in your home. Make sure the fan is turned off at the wall before changing this setting.

If that doesn't work, remove the lighting assembly and verify that the controls are connected in the space behind it. There are generally three screws around the edge of the plate where the lights attach to the fan. It may be helpful to have a second person safely assisting you. The colors there are generally white, black, and green that match the connections above. Red and/or blue may be used for the control wires in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the problem.  The remote was programmed incorrectly from the manufacturer.  I had to move the program switches to the "on" position, which is the default and tada it worked.